# Why MySQL DISTINCT "breaks" sorting order?

Tags: mysql, sql

The `example` table:

```
+------+------+
| nid  | lang |
+------+------+
|    9 | en   |
|   55 | en   |
|   47 | en   |
|   27 | nb   |
|    9 | nb   |
|   33 | ch   |
|   12 | pl   |
|   27 | en   |
|   10 | en   |
+------+------+
```

The query:

```
SELECT nid, lang FROM example WHERE lang IN ('nb', 'en')
ORDER BY CASE lang WHEN 'nb' THEN 0 WHEN 'en' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC;
```

The result:

```
+------+------+
| nid  | lang |
+------+------+
|   27 | nb   |
|    9 | nb   |
|    9 | en   |
|   55 | en   |
|   47 | en   |
|   27 | en   |
|   10 | en   |
+------+------+
```

So far so good, but I don't want duplicate `nid`s and don't need `lang` column. So when I add DISTINCT I get this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nid FROM example WHERE lang IN ('nb', 'en')
ORDER BY CASE lang WHEN 'nb' THEN 0 WHEN 'en' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC;
+------+
| nid  |
+------+
|   27 |
|   47 |
|   10 |
|    9 |
|   55 |
+------+
```

That is totally **not** what I wanted. However if I add `order by nid` I get this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nid FROM example WHERE lang IN ('nb', 'en')
ORDER BY CASE lang WHEN 'nb' THEN 0 WHEN 'en' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC, nid ASC;
+------+
| nid  |
+------+
|   27 |
|    9 |
|   10 |
|   47 |
|   55 |
+------+
```

This is more or less what I wanted. The order of values is weird but I can live with that. The most important thing is that result is correctly sorted by `lang` filed.

**But here is the real issue:** that was just a test query with example table. The real problem I'm facing is that the query is built automatically by some PHP code that I can't change.

The query that causes me problems looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  node.nid AS nid,
  node.nid AS node_nid,
  'node' AS field_data_field_image_node_entity_type,
  'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type
FROM
  node node LEFT JOIN field_data_body field_data_body
    ON node.nid = field_data_body.entity_id
    AND (field_data_body.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_body.deleted = '0')
WHERE
  (( (node.promote <> '0') AND (node.status = '1') )AND(( (field_data_body.language IN ('nb', 'en', 'en')) )))
ORDER BY
  CASE field_data_body.language WHEN 'nb' THEN 0 WHEN 'en' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC, node_nid ASC;
```

The problem with this query is that I don't get the sorting that I want. If there is no `DISTINCT` I get something like this:

```
+----------+
| node_nid |
+----------+
|        9 |
|       27 |
|        9 |
|       10 |
|       27 |
|       28 |
...
```

Sorting is OK, but I have to get rid of duplicates. But if I add `DISTINCT` I get this:

```
+----------+
| node_nid |
+----------+
|        9 |
|       10 | <-- this shouldn't be here
|       27 |
|       28 |
|       29 |
|       30 |
...
```

Since I deal with automatically generated query I have limited possibilities for changing it. I have some control over it but it's fairly limited. For example I can't add `GROUP BY`. **I would like to understand why I get this sorting order and maybe then I'll be able to find workaround.**

Comment: Try removing `node.nid AS nid,`